# how to properly iterate through array of post objects retrieved through Wp Rest Api in react js

Tags: javascript, wordpress, rest, reactjs, ecmascript-6

hello :) i am working on wp rest api and react js and i successfully retrieved data from wp rest api and displayed it, but its not the proper way to display data in react. console is showing the error message of ' Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop ' . I read the document in react regarding the issue but didn't understood . Here is what i have written so far. Any help would be great thank you

```
      class Home extends React.Component{
      componentDidMount(){
        const API_URL = 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/';
        this.serverRequest = $.get(API_URL, function (result) {
          this.setState({
            result:result,
            loaded:true
          });
        }.bind(this));
      }
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state ={result:null,loaded:false};
        autoBind(this);
      }
      render(){
        if (this.state.loaded) {
          return(
            <div>
                {this.state.result && <Portfolio data = {this.state.result}/>}
            </div>
          )
        }
        return(
          <div>loading...
          </div>
        )

      }
    }
    export default Home;
```

and the Portfolio component to which prop data is passed renders the data like this which is not the proper way

```
class Portfolio extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    autoBind(this);
  }
  render(){
  var contents=[];
  for (var i = 0; i < this.props.data.length; i++) {
    if (this.props.data[i].categories[0] == 5) {
      var productImage ={
        backgroundImage:'url('+ this.props.data[i].featured_image + ')',
        backgroundSize: '100% 100%'
      }
      contents.push(
            <div  id="portfolio-product-item" style ={productImage} >
              <div id ="portfolio-product-item-details" >
                <h3>{this.props.data[i].slug}</h3>
                <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.data[i].content.rendered}} />
              </div>
            </div>
      );
    }
  }
    return(
      <section className="portfolio">
           {contents}
      </section>
    )
  }
}
export default Portfolio;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your `Portfolio` component cleaner.

I suggest, split the logic and create a separate method from the main render.

```js
class Portfolio extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    autoBind(this);
  }

  renderPortfolioOption(index, option) {
    const { data } = this.props;

    if (option.categories[0] == 5) {
      var productImage ={
        backgroundImage:'url('+ option.featured_image + ')',
        backgroundSize: '100% 100%'
      }

      return(
        <div key={index} id="portfolio-product-item" style ={productImage} >
          <div id ="portfolio-product-item-details" >
            <h3>{option.slug}</h3>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: option.content.rendered}} />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;

    if (data.length) return null;

    return(
      <section className="portfolio">
        { data.map((index, option) => { return this.renderPortfolioOption(index, option); }) }
      </section>
    )
  }
}

export default Portfolio;
```

Comment: Thank you :) , this is a lot cleaner code, i am just a beginner in react, but in the render part of portfolio component , if statement is returning null and nothing is displayed and also unique "key" prop error is not solved , can you address these issues?

Comment: What will you display if you don't have any data? and you can solve the "key" problem by adding the parameter "index" in the map function :)  look how does map function works here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 2):

I haven't went over all of your code, just relating to the "key" error you got. 
The issue is here -

```
contents.push(
        <div  id="portfolio-product-item" style ={productImage} >
          <div id ="portfolio-product-item-details" >
            <h3>{this.props.data[i].slug}</h3>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.data[i].content.rendered}} />
          </div>
        </div>
  );
```

The father div with the id of `portfolio-product-item` should also have an attribute `key` so the proper way to write it is -

```
contents.push(
        <div  key={i} id="portfolio-product-item" style ={productImage} >
          <div id ="portfolio-product-item-details" >
            <h3>{this.props.data[i].slug}</h3>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.data[i].content.rendered}} />
          </div>
        </div>
  );
```

Have a look at - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children for further info.

Comment: thank you :) that solved my problem, actually there were more of parent div i omitted in the code, because it would be too hectic to read , thank you again :)